# How to calculate the distance between the Best Fit Curve and the data points?

Tags: r

[image]

Hello Everyone!

I am fairly new to R programming and hence I have a small doubt regarding the distance (or offset) of the data-set points from their Best-fit Curve. 
The given figure shows some points and a Best-fit Curve for those points.
As we can see some points are very far away from the Best-fit curve and I want to write a code which will tell me the distance (or offset) of all the points from the curve. Then I want to display all the points that are far away from the curve.
     I have the equation of the curve and all the data points. The curve has an exponential equation.
     The uploaded image is just a approximation of the real figure. I drew this one just as an example.
     If someone can tell me what method or functions shoul be used here then it would be a big help.

Thank You.

Comment: The "method" is to load the datapoint (x and y values), use the x values to compute `y_curve = f(x)` and the classical distance of your points from the curve is `y-y_curve`.

Comment: thanks a lot @antoine-sac. This sure helps me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many R situations you will actually fit the data with a function such as `lm` or `loess` or a `glm` for instance and the model summary will save residuals with the result.

If you indeed have your own equation then you simply want to take those values of x from the data points - calculate the equation y-values, then subtract them from the corresponding data y-values.

e.g. a toy example

```
# decay function
x= 1:50
start= 80
decay=0.95
equation_y=start*(decay^x)
plot(x,equation_y, type="l")

# simulated data points
data_y = equation_y + rnorm(50, sd=3)
points(x,data_y, col="red")

# the differences
equation_y - data_y
```

Comment: thanks a lot @Stephen. This indeed helps me.